# Unable to find styles-l.css original path in custom theme

Tags: magento2, static-content, styles

I want to add/modify some styles to `styles-l.css`, but i am unabl to identify the original path location, as i mentioned the below static content file path.

```
pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/css/styles-l.css
```

Can any one tell me the original location of the `styles-l.css` for the above path.

Comment: I was searching for this file at global file search in root folder, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

styles-l.css and styles-m.css are files generated by less compiler from all module files. If you want to modify its content you need to create your own theme in app/design/frontend. In your theme create file module folder (ie. Magento_Checkout) and in it path like `web/css/source/_module.less`. In that less file add your own styles which will be included in the `style-l.css`. So if your theme is in `app/design/frontend/MyStore/default` then your styles for checkout should be in `app/design/frontend/MyStore/default/Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/_module.less`.

Comment: Thanks, the file is getting loaded by /app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_CatalogSearch/web/css/source/_modules.less